# gosec unable to locate importing dir

Tags: go, continuous-integration, github-actions, code-auditing

I'm having a bit of trouble running [gosec](https://github.com/securego/gosec) with my current setup, both inside my local development machine and GitHub Actions.

When every time it ran this command `gosec aminogo/*.go` it gives the same set or errors

```
Golang errors in file: [aminogo/get_user_blogs_from_community.go]:

  > [line 0 : column 0] - importing dir "aminogo/get_user_blogs_from_community.go": cannot find package "." in:
    aminogo/get_user_blogs_from_community.go
```

to a extend of every file in my package directory

But when I ran the same code to a unit test via `go test` and build via `go build`, it works just fine without any package importing related errors

Already tried:

- Setting up a GOPATH inside the CI environment
- Moving the source code inside a GOPATH direction

```
env:
      ...
      CI: "true"
      GOPATH: ${{ github.workspace }}
      GO111MODULE: on
```

[image: CI Jobs Log Image]

All the CI jobs details and logs can be found in [here](https://github.com/AminoJS/AminoGo/runs/532247130?check_suite_focus=true)

The CI configuration file can be found [here](https://github.com/AminoJS/AminoGo/blob/master/.github/workflows/go.yml)

Thank you